# Shell script to create directories

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I'm trying to create a simple shell script for recursively creating directories inside a list of directories.

I have the next file structure:
A directory called v_79, containing a list of "dirs" (from dir_0 to dir_210), and inside each of them there are several directories called ENSG00000??????, where '?' stands for a character between [0-9].

I would like to create a directory called "my_dir" inside every one of the ENSG00000????? dirs.

I know how to create a directory once being inside each of the dir_XX 's,

```
    for i in ENSG00000??????; do mkdir $i/my_dir; done
```

but I don't know how to create the directory that I need, in the v_79 directory.

Comment: This just needs an outer loop to iterate over the dir_0 to dir_210 structure

Comment: That's an incredibly large amount of directories to create - 422 million?? dir_0 to dir_210 = 211 x ENSG00000000000 to ENSG00000999999 = 1,000,000 + another million for the my_dir's per directory, so 2 million per dir_n = 422 million.  Unless you have explained something wrong, you'll struggle to get that on to any file system.  Or are the ENSG00000?????? already existing?

Comment: "I know how to create a directory once being inside ... " - no, I don't think you do :-) That will only attempt to create directories that already exist.

Comment: @Orbling: Not in every directory must there be 1.000.000 dirs; (from 0 to 999.999). In fact its no more than 100 dir with the name ENSG?????? the numbers are only for nomenclature purposes. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your current directory contains directory "v_79", then

```
for dir in v_79/dir_{0..210}/ENSG00000??????; do mkdir $dir/my_dir; done
```

I wonder if that might give you an "argument list too long" error, in which case `find` is the way to go.

Comment: Its perfect, glenn. This did the job. Thx so much!

Answer (score 3):

If current dir is v_79, you can use a combination of `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -name 'ENSG00000......' -type d | xargs -I DIR mkdir DIR/my_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir -p v_79/dir{0,1}{1,2,3}
```

will create the directories v79/dir01, v79/dir02, v79/dir03, v79/dir11, v79/dir12 and v79/dir13 even if v_79 does not exist.

The -p options will create all required directories recursively.

Comment: The directories dir_xx already exist; i don't need to create them, and as @mouviciel said, it doesn't create the my_dir directory inside. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can do so from your v_79 directory:

```
for i in `find . -type d -name "ENSG00000??????"`; do mkdir $i/my_dir; done
```

Comment: This will create directories called `my_dir` inside of directories in the current directory called `find`, `-type`, `d`, `-name` and `ENSG00000??????`, but only if those directories already exist. You meant to say `for i in $(find . -type d -name "ENSG00000??????") ; do mkdir -i $i/my_dir ; done`, but this will also only create the subdirectory if the parent already exists.

Answer (score 1):

this is for `dry run` - if satisfied, delete the echo before mkdir

```
echo ./v_79/**/ENSG* | xargs -I% echo mkdir %/my_dir #or
echo ./v_79/**/dir_*/ENSG* | xargs -I% echo mkdir %/my_dir
```

you need for this bash4 and "shopt -s globstar" (e.g. in your profile)

If you have too much directories, you may get "argument list too long" error (for the 1st echo). In this case the the solution with the `find` is better

```
find v_79 -type d -print | grep '/ENSG' | xargs -I% echo mkdir %/my_dir
```

- find all directories in v_79
- filter out only these with name ENSG (you can add more "filters")
- run (echo) mkdir for the result

is somewhere in the path can be space, modify the above with:

```
find v_79 -type d -print0 | grep -z '/ENSG' | xargs -0 -I% echo mkdir %/my_dir
```

Also, you can limit the depth of the find command, e.g.:

```
find v_79 -depth 2 -type d -print0 | grep -z '/ENSG' | xargs -0 -I% echo mkdir %/my_dir
```

again, all above is for the dry run - remove the echo for the run. ;)

Comment: I already did it with the solution in the first answer. :)
Anyway, i will vote up your solution, because as I m a newb, its always interesting a solution with the code explained as u did... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the -p option, then your work will done.

BTW: -p option for mkdir command means "no error if existing, make parent directories as needed"

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
mkdir v_79/dir_{0,1,2}{,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/ENSG00000??????/my_dir
```